# How to make PHP to handle multiple lines output?

Tags: php

I'm struggling with this for a day now...
I have an OS command that returns several lines of output:

```
root@downloader:/var/www/html# /usr/local/bin/sdm120c -a 1 -P N -S 2 -j 20 /dev/ttyUSB0
Voltage: 248.00 V
Current: 16.29 A
Power: 4000.40 W
Active Apparent Power: 4014.28 VA
Reactive Apparent Power: -339.60 VAR
Power Factor: 1.00
Phase Angle: 0.00 Degree
Frequency: 50.00 Hz
Import Active Energy: 22726178 Wh
Export Active Energy: 252806 Wh
Total Active Energy: 22978984 Wh
Import Reactive Energy: 1136648 VARh
Export Reactive Energy: 2343577 VARh
Total Reactive Energy: 3480225 VARh
OK
```

I'm now trying to get this output via web through a simple PHP script, so I'm doing:

```
<?php
echo (exec('/usr/local/bin/sdm120c -a 1 -P N -S 2 -j 20 /dev/ttyUSB0'));
?>
```

However, the result is always "OK", which is the last line of the output.

My first idea was to "grep" the needed info in the OS command, and run it multiple times as needed, like:

`echo (exec('/usr/local/bin/sdm120c -a 1 -P N -S 2 -j 20 /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep -i Power:'));`

and it would suffice if I just needed one line of output.
The problem is that I can't run the OS command more often than once every 3 or 4 seconds, so since I need multiple lines, I can't really use this alternative...

Any idea how to get all the OS command output to be shown in the PHP request?

Comment: As described in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec) add a variable to the `exec` call to have the results returned in an array.

Comment: Alternatively you might want to look at wrapper around the core functions that make handling the command/output a bit easier. For instance Symfony provides a [Process component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#usage) you could use

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments from @RiggsFolly and @Dave, the following snipped works:

```
<?php
exec('/usr/local/bin/sdm120c -a 1 -P N -S 2 -j 20 /dev/ttyUSB0', $output);
print_r($output[2]);
print_r($output[4]);
 ?>
```